# FIWARE Cygnus -> cartodb sinks.NGSISink: Persistence error, 400 Bad request

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I'm trying to connect cygnus (1.4.0_SNAPSHOT) to cartodb. I run it locally, and I use a script to send a notification to cygnus. The script runs Ok, but cygnus says:

```
ERROR sinks.NGSISink: Persistence error (The query 'INSERT INTO jcarneroatos.x002fpeoplelocation (recvtime,fiwareservicepath,entityid,entitytype,the_geom) VALUES ('2016-10-31T19:04:00.994Z','/peoplelocation','Person:1','Person',ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint({"coordinates":[-4.423032856,36.721290055]), 4326))' could not be executed. CartoDB response: 400 Bad Request)
```

Anyone knows what could be happening? Below I put my config files for information, thanks!

My username at CARTO is "jcarneroatos", and the domain is https://jcarneroatos.carto.com. This is the script I'm using to simulate the notification from Orion Context Broker:

```
#/bin/bash
HOST=localhost
PORT=5050
SERVICE=jcarneroatos
SUBSERVICE=/peoplelocation

#send notification
NOTIFICATION=$(\
curl http://$HOST:$PORT/notify \
    -v -s -S \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    --header "Fiware-Service: $SERVICE" \
    --header "Fiware-ServicePath: $SUBSERVICE" \
    -d '
    {
        "contextResponses": [
            {
                "contextElement": {
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "metadatas": [
                                {
                                    "name": "location",
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "value": "WGS84"
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "location",
                            "type": "geo:json",
                            "value": {
                                "coordinates": [
                                    -4.423032856,
                                    36.721290055
                                ],
                                "type": "Point"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "id": "Person:1",
                    "isPattern": "false",
                    "type": "Person"
                },
                "statusCode": {
                    "code": "200",
                    "reasonPhrase": "OK"
                }
            }
        ],
        "originator": "localhost",
        "subscriptionId": "58178396634ded66caac35b2"
    }')
if [ -z "$NOTIFICATION" ]; then
    echo "Ok"
else
    echo $NOTIFICATION
fi
```

This is the structure of the dataset at cartodb:

```
x002fpeoplelocation
cartodb_id | the_geom | entityid | entitytype | fiwareservicepath | recvtime
  number   | geometry |  string  |   string   |      string       |   date
```

This is the cygnus config file:

```
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = cartodb-sink
cygnusagent.channels =cartodb-channel

cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = cartodb-channel
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = jcarneroatos
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /peoplelocation
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.NGSIGroupingInterceptor$Builder
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /home/cygnus/APACHE_FLUME_HOME/conf/grouping_rules.conf

cygnusagent.sinks.cartodb-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICartoDBSink
cygnusagent.sinks.cartodb-sink.channel = cartodb-channel
cygnusagent.sinks.cartodb-sink.enable_grouping = false
cygnusagent.sinks.cartodb-sink.enable_name_mappings = false
cygnusagent.sinks.cartodb-sink.enable_lowercase = false
cygnusagent.sinks.cartodb-sink.data_model = dm-by-service-path
cygnusagent.sinks.cartodb-sink.keys_conf_file = /home/cygnus/APACHE_FLUME_HOME/conf/cartodb_keys.conf
cygnusagent.sinks.cartodb-sink.flip_coordinates = false
cygnusagent.sinks.cartodb-sink.enable_raw = true
cygnusagent.sinks.cartodb-sink.enable_distance = false
cygnusagent.sinks.cartodb-sink.batch_size = 100
cygnusagent.sinks.cartodb-sink.batch_timeout = 30
cygnusagent.sinks.cartodb-sink.batch_ttl = 10
cygnusagent.sinks.cartodb-sink.backend.max_conns = 500
cygnusagent.sinks.cartodb-sink.backend.max_conns_per_route = 100

cygnusagent.channels.cartodb-channel.type = memory
cygnusagent.channels.cartodb-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnusagent.channels.cartodb-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

And finally the cartodb_keys.conf file (without key):

```
{
   "cartodb_keys": [
      {
         "username": "jcarneroatos",
         "endpoint": "https://jcarneroatos.carto.com",
         "key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"   
      }
   ]
}
```

**Update:**
After executing Cygnus in DEBUG mode and check the logs, it seems that CARTO is returning:

```
{"error":["syntax error at or near \"{\""]}
```

This the complete log: http://pastebin.com/p9VyUU8n

Comment: Could you please run Cygnus in DEBUG mode and update your post with the log traces?

Comment: Hi @frb , thanks for answering. Please check the update above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after offline discussion with @Javi Carnero, we found there was a bug in Cygnus code related to the way Carto differentiates among "enterprise" and "personal" accounts. First ones allow for PostgreSQL schemas per user under the enterprise organization, while second ones have "hardcoded" schemas named `public`. Since the notified FIWARE service was used as the schema name, Cygnus was not properly working for "personal" accounts.

Such a bug has been fixed:

- Issue: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/1382
- PR: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/1393

At the moment of writting this, the bug is fixed in `master` branch. By the end of sprint/month Cygnus 1.7.0 will be released, including this fix.

Please observe my previous answer is perfectly valid if you have an "enterprise" account. Anyway, I'll edit it in order to explain this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `geo:json` type is not currently supported by `NGSICartoDBSink`. This sink understands ceratain ways of notifying geolocated attributes, according to Orion Context Broker specification; these ones:

- Using the `geo:point` type, and sending the coordinates in the value field with format `"latitude, longitude"`.
- Using the `location` metadata, of type `string` and value `WGS84`, and sending the coordinates in the value field with format `"latitude, longitude"`.

Please observe:

- The above options are exclussive, i.e. cannot be used at the same time.
- The `location` metadata is deprecated in Orion, nevertheless it can be still used.

While `geo:json` is supported (I'll start working on that, it could be ready during this sprint/month), I'll recommend you to use the `geo:point` type.

**EDIT 1**

I'm adding here an example of Cygnus execution, when receiving a notification involving a geolocated attribute (`geo:point` type).

Cygnus version:

```
1.6.0
```

Cygnus configuration:

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources = http-source
cygnus-ngsi.sinks = raw-sink
cygnus-ngsi.channels = raw-channel

cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.channels = raw-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = default
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp

cygnus-ngsi.sinks.raw-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICartoDBSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.raw-sink.channel = raw-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.raw-sink.enable_grouping = false
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.raw-sink.keys_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/cartodb_keys.conf
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.raw-sink.swap_coordinates = false
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.raw-sink.enable_raw = true
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.raw-sink.enable_distance = false
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.raw-sink.enable_raw_snapshot = false
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.raw-sink.data_model = dm-by-entity
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.raw-sink.batch_size = 50
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.raw-sink.batch_timeout = 10
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.raw-sink.batch_ttl = 0
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.raw-sink.batch_retries = 5000

cygnus-ngsi.channels.raw-channel.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.channels.CygnusMemoryChannel
cygnus-ngsi.channels.raw-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnus-ngsi.channels.raw-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Create the table:

```
$ curl -X GET -G "https://<my_user>.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?api_key=<my_key>" --data-urlencode "q=CREATE TABLE x002ftestxffffx0043ar1xffffx0043ar (recvTime text, fiwareServicePath text, entityId text, entityType text, speed float, speed_md text, the_geom geometry(POINT,4326))"
{"rows":[],"time":0.005,"fields":{},"total_rows":0}
```

Script simulating a notification:

```
$ cat notification.sh
#!/bin/sh

URL=$1

if [ "$2" != "" ]
then
   SERVICE=$2
else
   SERVICE=default
fi

if [ "$3" != "" ]
then
   SERVICE_PATH=$3
else
   SERVICE_PATH=/
fi

curl $URL -v -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'User-Agent: orion/0.10.0' --header "Fiware-Service: $SERVICE" --header "Fiware-ServicePath: $SERVICE_PATH" -d @- 
<<EOF
{
  "subscriptionId" : "51c0ac9ed714fb3b37d7d5a8",
  "originator" : "localhost",
  "contextResponses" : [
    {
      "contextElement" : {
        "attributes" : [
          {
            "name" : "speed",
            "type" : "float",
            "value" : "$6"
          },
          {
            "name" : "the_geom",
            "type" : "geo:point",
            "value" : "$4, $5"
          }
        ],
        "type" : "Car",
        "isPattern" : "false",
        "id" : "Car1"
      },
      "statusCode" : {
        "code" : "200",
        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF
```

Script execution:

```
$ ./notification.sh http://localhost:5050/notify <my_user> /test 40.40 -3.4 120
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 5050 (#0)
> POST /notify HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5050
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> Accept: application/json
> User-Agent: orion/0.10.0
> Fiware-Service: <my_user>
> Fiware-ServicePath: /test
> Content-Length: 569
> 
* upload completely sent off: 569 out of 569 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Cygnus logs upon notification reception:

```
time=2016-12-02T13:48:27.310UTC | lvl=INFO | corr=eb73b8d5-af9b-48ea-8ce7-ff21edc957f3 | trans=eb73b8d5-af9b-48ea-8ce7-ff21edc957f3 | srv=<my_user> | subsrv=/test | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[282] : [NGSIRestHandler] Starting internal transaction (eb73b8d5-af9b-48ea-8ce7-ff21edc957f3)
time=2016-12-02T13:48:27.312UTC | lvl=INFO | corr=eb73b8d5-af9b-48ea-8ce7-ff21edc957f3 | trans=eb73b8d5-af9b-48ea-8ce7-ff21edc957f3 | srv=<my_user> | subsrv=/test | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[299] : [NGSIRestHandler] Received data ({  "subscriptionId" : "51c0ac9ed714fb3b37d7d5a8",  "originator" : "localhost",  "contextResponses" : [    {      "contextElement" : {        "attributes" : [          {            "name" : "speed",            "type" : "float",            "value" : "120"          },          {            "name" : "the_geom",            "type" : "geo:point",            "value" : "40.40, -3.4"          }        ],        "type" : "Car",        "isPattern" : "false",        "id" : "Car1"      },      "statusCode" : {        "code" : "200",        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"      }    }  ]})
time=2016-12-02T13:48:36.404UTC | lvl=INFO | corr=eb73b8d5-af9b-48ea-8ce7-ff21edc957f3 | trans=eb73b8d5-af9b-48ea-8ce7-ff21edc957f3 | srv=<my_user> | subsrv=/test | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=persistRawAggregation | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICartoDBSink[553] : [raw-sink] Persisting data at NGSICartoDBSink. Schema (<my_user>), Table (x002ftestxffffx0043ar1xffffx0043ar), Data (('2016-12-02T13:48:27.381Z','/test','Car1','Car',ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(40.40,-3.4), 4326),'120','[]'))
time=2016-12-02T13:48:38.237UTC | lvl=INFO | corr=eb73b8d5-af9b-48ea-8ce7-ff21edc957f3 | trans=eb73b8d5-af9b-48ea-8ce7-ff21edc957f3 | srv=<my_user> | subsrv=/test | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=processNewBatches | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[514] : Finishing internal transaction (eb73b8d5-af9b-48ea-8ce7-ff21edc957f3)
```

Getting the data:

```
$ curl -X GET -G "https://<my_user>.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?api_key=<my_key>" --data-urlencode "q=select * from x002ftestxffffx0043ar1xffffx0043ar"
{"rows":[{"recvtime":"2016-12-02T13:48:27.381Z","fiwareservicepath":"/test","entityid":"Car1","entitytype":"Car","speed":120,"speed_md":"[]","the_geom":"0101000020E610000033333333333344403333333333330BC0"}],"time":0.001,"fields":{"recvtime":{"type":"string"},"fiwareservicepath":{"type":"string"},"entityid":{"type":"string"},"entitytype":{"type":"string"},"speed":{"type":"number"},"speed_md":{"type":"string"},"the_geom":{"type":"geometry"}},"total_rows":1}
```

**EDIT 2**

This answer is only valid if you own an "enterprise" Carto account. Please, see my other answer to this question.

Comment: Ok I changed the [notification script](http://pastebin.com/S2Ga0Lf7) but cartodb returns `"{"error":["relation \"jcarneroatos.x002fpeoplelocation\" does not exist"]}"` - see relevant part of the log [here](http://pastebin.com/qBPXpcP9).

However if I take manually the GET url and remove the "jcarneroatos." part the url works. Maybe is a bug with the "service" part?

**SUGGESTION**: the notation used in my original notification script is taken from fiware-device-simulator. Would be really nice to support this notation for architectures like simulator -> orion -> cygnus -> cartodb

Comment: Ummm, please check my update, I've added a complete example including notification, insertion and query. Try reproducing it.

Comment: Hi, the geo:json type is finally available at `master` branch of fiware-cygnus ;)

Comment: Hi @frb, I can't reproduce your update example because I don't know the notifications you are sending to cygnus. Following the docs, I am using the name "x002fpeoplelocation" because I am using dm-by-service-path without distance analysis. The problem here is that the cartdodb sink is asking for the relation <service>.x002<service_path> while it should ask only for x002<service_path> (see previous comment). Also I tested the geo:json feature (removing the <service>. from the url generated), and I am getting: {"error":["Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)"]}

Comment: I've added all the required information for reproducing the example.

Comment: thank you very much for the update. Using 1.6.0 (master) and your example, I am getting exactly the same error: [ERROR - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:527)] Persistence error (The query 'INSERT INTO jcarneroatos.x002ftestxffffx0043ar1xffffx0043ar (recvtime,... {"error":["relation \"jcarneroatos.x002ftestxffffx0043ar1xffffx0043ar\" does not exist"]} However if I remove the "<service>." part of the query and run it on web browser it works. I had also to change cartodb.com to carto.com in the examples.

Comment: You have to create the table in advance, previous to Cygnus execution. Here you can find an explanation about why Cygnus cannot create the table by itself: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/cygnus-ngsi/flume_extensions_catalogue/ngsi_cartodb_sink.md#section2.3.5 . Anyway, if you followed my example, you should have created the table... what was the response of the curl in charge of creating the table?

Comment: yes the table is created in advance. The creation of the table worked as expected (changing cartodb.com to carto.com), same result as your example.